# Uploading file yields 406 (Not Acceptable) error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to upload a file using sample code. I am not getting any compilation errors but a `406 Not Acceptable` error message. What does this mean?

**POST request:**

```
Started POST "/files/upload" for 10.15.24.38 at 2012-06-22 21:18:11 -0400
Processing by FilesController#upload as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"wfpBi3Y8KgmqitXrh4fZ3xfun73mWOfXiTQ+J7bdfWU=", "user_id"=>"231",
"button"=>"", "upload"=>{"datafile"=>"ws_1920x1080.jpg"}}
```

**View:**

```
<%= form_tag files_upload_path, :remote => true, :method => :post, :multipart => true do %>
#The form has some other values too. I am keeping it short here.  
<p>
<label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :
<%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
 def upload
    #The controller has some other values too, that are not related to file upload. 

    if params[:datafile]
    uploaded_io = params[:upload][:datafile]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end
    end

    if params[:user_id] 
    #do some extra stuff
    end 

    respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    end 

 end
```

**Error:**

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2736ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

Comment: there's not enough info here. Please paste the entire controller action.

Comment: @x1a4 - The controller is too large. And the code here is the only relevant code for uploading a file. Even if I completely remove this upload code from the controller then still I get the error `Completed 406 Not Acceptable`

Comment: You need to post the form and the full controller action.

Comment: Updated my question with some more code.

Comment: All we need to see is the action, not the entire controller. What's there still isn't enough information. The action will either render a response, or redirect somewhere. That's what you need to show.

Comment: @x1a4 - I actually render back as ajax using javascript.

Comment: @KapishM What are you using remotipart to upload the file since you can just directly upload a  file using ajax like normal form unless your using some sort of plugin or something like it

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to provide the answer but you're clearly missing `:multipart => true` in our `form_for` call as in:

```
<%= form_for @upload, :multipart => true do |f| %>
  Your form code here
<% end %>
```

And the not acceptable error happens because you're asking for HTML rendering but there is probably not  a `respond_to` piece answering to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed (in direct way) to upload files through remote request. Take a look here: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cant upload a file using `ajax` just by specifying `remote => true` you need some sort of plugin or something like it to do it like

`remotipart` , `plupload` , `uploadify`  or something like it .

so if you are not using any plugin then even if you specify `remote => true` the form would be sent as normal HTML request **instead of** `XMLHttpRequest`

Now since in your controller you have **removed**

`format.html` part as you are assuming that it would be an `ajax` request but in reality it is not (HTML request)

becoz Rails cannot find the appropriate format to respond back it is reporting `406 Not Acceptable`

Do your self a favor log the `request.xhr?` method in your controller.

something like

`logger.info "******************** #{request.xhr?} *********************"`

If `request.xhr?` return **nil** that specify that request is **not** an ajax request